# Inotifywait with counter does not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, inotify

I would like to run a command if there are 3 modifications events in the monitored directory.

I have tried this, however, even though it works with the `-m` option, it does not work without the `-m` option of `inotifywait`.

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while :
do
    { inotifywait -m -q -e modify /home/testDir && let count="$count + 1"; } || exit 1
    if [ "$count" -eq "3" ]; then
        #Do something.
        count=-250
    fi
done
```

**What do I want it do to?**

I want to monitor the MODIFY events in the directory and if there is a 3 number of modify events, I would like to run a command.

**What happens when I try**

This counter basically does not work without the `-m` option of the `inotifywait`, however it works if I use the `-m` option. I have to use the `-m` option. Otherwise, `inotifywait` misses some events.

Comment: Welcome, the `-m` option means *monitor*, is it not what you need? Also, you are wrapping the command in a while loop. Why is that? you don't need to run `inotifywait` multiple times.

Comment: Yeah for sure I need the `-m` option. How can I count the number of modify events occured without running the inotifywait `multiple` times? Can you illustrate me simple example?

Comment: @kkk001 the `modify` event is meant for files, not directories. Please clarify exactly what changes you want to monitor. **[edit]** the question adding the information, don't use the comments.